# Почему такое происходит c JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не пойму почему такое происходит, есть такой код:

```
    var input_quantity = _this.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().next().find('#input-quantity').val();
    var max_qty = _this.children().next('.input-option_qty').val();

     if (input_quantity > max_qty) {
            _this.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().next().find('#input-quantity').val(max_qty);
            
           console.log('код сработал');
     }

};
```

Код отрабатывает как нужно,
если в инпуте число больше чем в переменной max_qty
то в инпут подменяем на максимум доступное из max_qty

если в инпуте число от 10 включительно и до 19
то не срабатывает условие

например в инпуте 15, а в max_qty = 5

не работает именно когда в инпуте число 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19

С чем это связано?

Comment: "10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19" --- это не число. Нет такого числа в природе

Comment: Поменял дубликат. Ты сравниваешь строки, а нужно сравнивать числа.

Comment: Спасибо, понял!

Comment: Вместо `.parent().parent().parent()` используйте [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)